# How do I include an image in an HTML email created in Apex code? the <img> tag is not showing up for me

Tags: email

I'm attempting to create and send out email inside of an Apex controller. I'm querying the HtmlBody of another template (which has the image reference in it) but that doesn't show. I've also tried adding my own  tags with no luck.

Is there a control other than  I can use?

Comment: I've tried both:
<img src="https://c.cs59.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=***************&oid=*************" width="200">

AND

<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ZIPFileName,\'MyLogo.jpeg\')}" width="200">

Comment: can you edit the question and provide the code snipper?

Comment: htmlValue is the htmlValue field from the emailtemplate. I do string replacement to populate fields and then set to the email with setHtmlBody()

`
System.debug(htmlValue);
String headerImage = '<img src="https://c.cs59.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=*****************&oid=*************" width="200"><br/><br/>';
// String headerImage = '<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ZIPFileName,\'MyLogo.jpeg\')}" width="200"><br/><br/>';

        String baseHTML = htmlValue.remove('<![CDATA[').remove(']]>');
        baseHTML = headerImage + baseHTML;
`

Comment: The `img` tag is completely missing in the received email? Or is the reference to the image broken? One thing to keep in mind with images in emails is that you likely want the cache control on the image to be public (on the Static Resource). An issue you'll see with a service like Gmail is that Google's servers will actually extract images out of emails and then reference them via proxy URLs - and since Google's servers won't have permissions to files within your Salesforce org - that essentially breaks all of your email images by turning the proxies into broken images.

Comment: The img tag is completely missing, I don't see the broken image icon or anything. And the static resource is marked public

Comment: any luck on this? I did inserted img tag, but it is just a broken img icon